# Pyside QTableWidget does not wait for dialog to be accepted or rejected in click event

Tags: python, pyside

When I create a Dialog and test it outside of a QTableWidget, it seems to work fine, as in being modal and blocking.  However, when I embed it inside the cell_clicked method of a QTableWidget subclass(which is connected to the cellClicked) event, my dialog.exec_() method does not act modal, the method simply runs on by it, printing out result before I accept *or* reject.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import PySide.QtGui as qg
import PySide.QtCore as qc

class TableWidget(qg.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TableWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setRowCount(1)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['a','b'])
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(qc.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.cellClicked.connect(self.cell_clicked)
        self.setShowGrid(False)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
#        self.resizeColumnsToContents()

    def cell_clicked(self,row,column):
        print(row,column)
        self.d = Dialog1()
        result = self.d.exec_()
        print(result)
        if result:
            results = self.d.results()
            model = self.model()
            index = model.index(row,column)
            item = self.itemFromIndex(index)
            item.setData(index,results,qc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)

class Dialog1(qg.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog1,self).__init__()
        self.text_edit = qg.QLineEdit()
        button_ok = qg.QPushButton('Ok')
        button_cancel = qg.QPushButton('Cancel')

        sub_layout1 = qg.QHBoxLayout()
        sub_layout1.addWidget(button_ok)
        sub_layout1.addWidget(button_cancel)

        layout = qg.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        layout.addLayout(sub_layout1)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        button_ok.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        button_cancel.clicked.connect(self.reject)

    def results(self):
        return self.text_edit.text()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    import sys
    app = qg.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog1()
    result = dialog.exec_()
    print(result)    

    widget = TableWidget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_)
```

Comment: The dialog works fine with me (Python2.7.8 and PySide 1.2.2). You click a cell, it prints the coordinates and open the dialog. I click "ok", the dialog is closed, it prints "1".

Answer (score 1):

it was in the last line... I used

```
sys.exit(app.exec_)
```

instead of

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Doh!!!